# How can I solve this equation: $e^{2x^3 - 6x^2 + 3} = 0$

Tags: exponential-function

I don't remember what I supposed to do in this situation...I know that it's necessary transform both sides of the equation in the same base. However, what I need to do when i have a 0?

My equation: $e^{2x^3 - 6x^2 + 3} = 0$

Comment: Is $e^y$ _ever_ $0$?

Comment: yes Daniel...i don't know what should I do

Comment: it's wrong do this: e^(2x^3-6x^2+3) = e^0 isn't it?

Comment: Yes, $e^0 = 1$. Since $e^y \neq 0$ for all $y$, the equation has no solution.

Comment: You can consider the point $x$ at $-\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to know that $e^{\mathrm{something}}$ is never zero, so that doesn't have any solution. It is never negative, also. But, if you had $$e^{\mathrm{something}} = c > 0$$
we can take $\ln$ on both sides and get: $$\begin{align}\ln e^{\mathrm{something}} &= \ln c \\ \mathrm{something} &= \ln c\end{align}$$
That last equation you should be able to solve, normally. Don't be afraid of $\ln c$, it is just a number. Ok?

Comment: Thanks Ivo..I've been concluding this also...so...just to confirm: e^something = not exist (right?)

Comment: No. Actually, I meant that $e^{\mathrm{something}} \neq 0$, **whatever** something may be. In your exercise, you have an exponential equal to zero, but that is impossible, hence, no solution. The rest of my answer is how to go at the problem, if the exponential is equal to something positive, meaning that a solution does exist.